# Update hash value array from other array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
{
  "grey" => ["anf_94748_01_prod1", "anf_94748_01_model1", "anf_94748_01_model2"],
  "heather blue" => ["anf_106537_01_prod1", "anf_106537_01_model1", "anf_106537_01_model2"],
  "indigo" => [],
  "dark grey" => ["anf_94747_01_prod1"]
}
```

How can I replace its values according to an array of image ids:

```
[317, 318, 319, 320, 340, 358, 365]
```

If hash array is empty, then skip it and go to the next hash key, and assign id to that image. Desired output will be:

```
{
  "grey" => [317, 318, 319],
  "heather blue" => [320, 340, 358],
  "indigo" => [],
  "dark grey" => [365]
}
```

Comment: Igor, I have two suggestion: 1) format your code so that readers can read it without having to scroll horizontally; and 2) assign each example input (here just one hash) to a variable, so that readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them. For example,  `h = { "grey"=>...}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
h = {
  "grey" => ["anf_94748_01_prod1", "anf_94748_01_model1", "anf_94748_01_model2"],
  "heather blue" => ["anf_106537_01_prod1", "anf_106537_01_model1", "anf_106537_01_model2"],
  "indigo" => [],
  "dark grey" => ["anf_94747_01_prod1"]
}
a = [317, 318, 319, 320, 340, 358, 365]

h.each_value{|v| v.map!{a.shift}}
# =>
# {
#   "grey"=>[317, 318, 319],
#   "heather blue"=>[320, 340, 358],
#   "indigo"=>[],
#   "dark grey"=>[365]
# }
```

Comment: Good.  Alternatively, `v.replace(a.shift(v.size))`.

Answer (score 1):

As a variant of @sawa's answer, if you do not wish to mutate `h`, the OP's example hash, you could do this:

```
a = [317, 318, 319, 320, 340, 358, 365]

h.merge(h) { |_,v| a.shift(v.size) }
   #=> {"grey"=>[317, 318, 319], "heather blue"=>[320, 340, 358],
   #    "indigo"=>[], "dark grey"=>[365]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys present in both hashes, which here is all keys.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` is a good function for taking moving through a data structure while accumulating some result.

```
imgs = [317, 318, 319, 320, 340, 358, 365]
input = {"grey"=>["anf_94748_01_prod1", "anf_94748_01_model1", "anf_94748_01_model2"], "heather blue"=>["anf_106537_01_prod1", "anf_106537_01_model1", "anf_106537_01_model2"], "indigo"=>[], "dark grey"=>["anf_94747_01_prod1"]}

input.reduce({}) { |acc, (k, xs)| acc[k] = imgs.shift(xs.count); acc}

# => {"grey"=>[317, 318, 319], "heather blue"=>[320, 340, 358], "indigo"=>[], "dark grey"=>[365]}
```

Comment: Or preferably [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) since it exactly fits your description unlike `Enumerable#reduce`.